# html table printing "s " above itself?

Tags: html, html-table

Can someone please take the following html code and run it in a browser?

```
<table align="center" border="1">
<tr>
<td>Eastern</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Atlantic</td>
<td>Games Played</td>
<td>Wins</td>
<td>Losses</td>
<td>Overtime Losses</td>
<td>Points</td>
<td>Home</td>
<td>Road</td>
<td>Streak</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><? echo $pittname ?></td>
<td><? echo $pittGP ?></td>
<td><? echo $pittW ?></td>
<td><? echo $pittL ?></td>
<td><? echo $pittOL ?></td>
<td><? echo $pittP ?></td>
<td><? echo $pittH ?></td>
<td><? echo $pittR ?></td>
<td><? echo $pittS ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><? echo $phillname ?></td>
<td><? echo $phillGP ?></td>
<td><? echo $phillW ?></td>
<td><? echo $phillL ?></td>
<td><? echo $phillOL ?></td>
<td><? echo $phillP ?></td>
<td><? echo $phillH ?></td>
<td><? echo $phillR ?></td>
<td><? echo $phillS ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><? echo $nyrname ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyrGP ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyrW ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyrL ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyrOL ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyrP ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyrH ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyrR ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyrS ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><? echo $njname ?></td>
<td><? echo $njGP ?></td>
<td><? echo $njW ?></td>
<td><? echo $njL ?></td>
<td><? echo $njOL ?></td>
<td><? echo $njP ?></td>
<td><? echo $njH ?></td>
<td><? echo $njR ?></td>
<td><? echo $njS ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><? echo $nyiname ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyiGP ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyiW ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyiL ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyiOL ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyiP ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyiH ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyiR ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyiS ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Northeast</td>
<td>Games Played</td>
<td>Wins</td>
<td>Losses</td>
<td>Overtime Losses</td>
<td>Points</td>
<td>Home</td>
<td>Road</td>
<td>Streak</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><? echo $bstnname ?></td>
<td><? echo $bstnGP ?></td>
<td><? echo $bstnW ?></td>
<td><? echo $bstnL ?></td>
<td><? echo $bstnOL ?></td>
<td><? echo $bstnP ?></td>
<td><? echo $bstnH ?></td>
<td><? echo $bstnR ?></td>
<td><? echo $bstnS ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><? echo $trtoname ?></td>
<td><? echo $trtoGP ?></td>
<td><? echo $trtoW ?></td>
<td><? echo $trtoL ?></td>
<td><? echo $trtoOL ?></td>
<td><? echo $trtoP ?></td>
<td><? echo $trtoH ?></td>
<td><? echo $trtoR ?></td>
<td><? echo $trtoS ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><? echo $buffname ?></td>
<td><? echo $buffGP ?></td>
<td><? echo $buffW ?></td>
<td><? echo $buffL ?></td>
<td><? echo $buffOL ?></td>
<td><? echo $buffP ?></td>
<td><? echo $buffH ?></td>
<td><? echo $buffR ?></td>
<td><? echo $buffS ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><? echo $mntrlname ?></td>
<td><? echo $mntrlGP ?></td>
<td><? echo $mntrlW ?></td>
<td><? echo $mntrlL ?></td>
<td><? echo $mntrlOL ?></td>
<td><? echo $mntrlP ?></td>
<td><? echo $mntrlH ?></td>
<td><? echo $mntrlR ?></td>
<td><? echo $mntrlS ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><? echo $otowaname ?></td>
<td><? echo $otowaGP ?></td>
<td><? echo $otowaW ?></td>
<td><? echo $otowaL ?></td>
<td><? echo $otowaOL ?></td>
<td><? echo $otowaP ?></td>
<td><? echo $otowaH ?></td>
<td><? echo $otowaR ?></td>
<td><? echo $otowaS ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Southeast</td>
<td>Games Played</td>
<td>Wins</td>
<td>Losses</td>
<td>Overtime Losses</td>
<td>Points</td>
<td>Home</td>
<td>Road</td>
<td>Streak</td>
</tr>
<tr>
s<td><? echo $wjname ?></td>
<td><? echo $wjGP ?></td>
<td><? echo $wjW ?></td>
<td><? echo $wjL ?></td>
<td><? echo $wjOL ?></td>
<td><? echo $wjP ?></td>
<td><? echo $wjH ?></td>
<td><? echo $wjR ?></td>
<td><? echo $wjS ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
s<td><? echo $wcname ?></td>
<td><? echo $wcGP ?></td>
<td><? echo $wcW ?></td>
<td><? echo $wcL ?></td>
<td><? echo $wcOL ?></td>
<td><? echo $wcP ?></td>
<td><? echo $wcH ?></td>
<td><? echo $wcR ?></td>
<td><? echo $wcS ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
s<td><? echo $fpname ?></td>
<td><? echo $fpGP ?></td>
<td><? echo $fpW ?></td>
<td><? echo $fpL ?></td>
<td><? echo $fpOL ?></td>
<td><? echo $fpP ?></td>
<td><? echo $fpH ?></td>
<td><? echo $fpR ?></td>
<td><? echo $fpS ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
s<td><? echo $tblname ?></td>
<td><? echo $tblGP ?></td>
<td><? echo $tblW ?></td>
<td><? echo $tblL ?></td>
<td><? echo $tblOL ?></td>
<td><? echo $tblP ?></td>
<td><? echo $tblH ?></td>
<td><? echo $tblR ?></td>
<td><? echo $tblS ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
s<td><? echo $chname ?></td>
<td><? echo $chGP ?></td>
<td><? echo $chW ?></td>
<td><? echo $chL ?></td>
<td><? echo $chOL ?></td>
<td><? echo $chP ?></td>
<td><? echo $chH ?></td>
<td><? echo $chR ?></td>
<td><? echo $chS ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I feel very noobish for asking but have singled the problem  down to this table and can't figure out why is it printing "s"'s?

Comment: Sit. Check your code. You must have written `s` somewhere, by mistake, before table. Review your code. IMO this is not a question to ask.

Comment: We cannot run your PHP code for you... especially code like this without any context and so won't work properly anywhere else but in your own computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few lines like this:

```
s<td><? echo $wjname ?></td>
```

And this:

```
s<td><? echo $chname ?></td>
```

Answer (score 3):

They're in the output because you have them in the input:

```
:
<tr>
s<td><? echo $wjname ?></td>
<td><? echo $wjGP ?></td>
:
</tr>
<tr>
s<td><? echo $wcname ?></td>
<td><? echo $wcGP ?></td>
:
</tr>
<tr>
s<td><? echo $fpname ?></td>
<td><? echo $fpGP ?></td>
:
```

Now that explains where they're coming *from* but you may still be concerned as to where they're going *to.*

You may *think* it's a problem because the `s` characters are inside a `tr` and so shouldn't be outside of the table thusly:
[image]

But you'd be wrong. The [specification for `tr` under HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element), for example, states that the only child elements allowed are:

> Zero or more `td` or `th` elements.

Standalone text is part of the [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#flow-content) and is listed as allowable under (for example) [`td`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/tabular-data.html#the-td-element) but *not* `tr`. Hence, you're violating the standards and the browser can do whatever it pleases, up to and including annihilating a large section of space-time around your client machine :-)

If you want them in the table cells, they should go in between the `td` and `/td` elements. But I suspect they shouldn't be there at all - it looks like you made a typo and then cut'n'pasted it to a few different places.

Comment: Browsers can do whatever they like, but the tradition (since the early days of HTML tables) has been that they collect all the spurious content together and emit it before they start rendering the table. The reason is probably that they read the entire table before they know the column widths and can render any of it, and at this point, they just flush out whatever they saw outside cells.

Comment: What they do and what they should do are two different things. In my opinion, all computers should be hooked up to the testicles of developers to deliver a short, sharp electrical jolt when people violate standards. Developers would then become a much more circumspect group of people. Adjust appropriately if your developers are female :-)

Answer (score 2):

there are s's before some of your `<td>` tags

Answer (score 2):

you have "s", written outside the td tags....

Comment: thank you, i wonder why the s appear out of the table liek that?

Comment: @Shawn: stop wondering, just read my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some lines in your code containt this 's' before the `<td>` Tag, like:

```
s<td><? echo $wjname ?></td>
```

and:

```
s<td><? echo $wcname ?></td>
```